# How to convert CURSOR based query in to SET based

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, sql-server-2012, rbar

I'm not a expert on SQL and I'm working on a huge SQL code and unfortunately it has a CURSOR which handles another two nested CURSORS within it (totally three cursors inside a stored procedure), which handles millions of data to be DELETE,UPDATE and INSERT.

This takes a whole lot of time (more than 13 hrs and eventually  gets an error 'cursor names datasets already exists') because of row by row execution and I'm trying to modify this in to SET based approach and I'm stuck how to do the INSERT,DELETE and UPDATE while converting into SET based approach.Or in other words I couldn't do all the INSERT,DELETE and UPDATE by replacing them in JOINS.

I know this is a large code and might not be right attempt to post here but I already to put this in a simple manner in another post and people doesn't get the idea of my question so I'm putting here the actual code.

This is the code I'm working on :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_Upload]  WITH RECOMPILE 
as
set NoCount on

DECLARE
    @StartTime      datetime,
    @EndTime        datetime,
    @DataID         uniqueidentifier,
    @CollectionDate datetime,
    @Status         int,
    @PeriodID       int,
    @EndDate        datetime,
    @GroupID        uniqueidentifier,
    @ProjectID      INT,
    @FAID           uniqueidentifier,
    @UploadID       int ,
    @Createdate datetime


declare @projects table(
    [ProjectID] [INT],
    [Title] [varchar](255) ,
    [currency] [int] ,
    [Cost_Until_Today] [float] ,
    [StartDate] [datetime] ,
    [EndDate] [datetime] ,
    [MisID] [uniqueidentifier] ,
    [SystemStatus] [int] ,
    [FacilitatingAgency] [uniqueidentifier] ,
    [SyncMode] [int] )

 INSERT @projects
 SELECT ID, PROJECTNAME, PROJECTCURRENCY_ID, Cost_Until_Today, PROJECTESTABLISHEDDATE, EndDate, MisID, 4, FacilitatingAgency, SyncMode 
 FROM [dbo].[T_PROJECTS] /*thsi is the source table where every projectIDs need to be processed*/



 IF exists ( select  *
            from    dbo.sysobjects
            where   id = object_id(N'[dbo].[datasets]') and objectproperty(id, N'IsTable') = 1 ) 
    DROP Table [dbo].datasets


    SELECT mgd.Gd_ID, mg.Grp_ID, mgd.Gd_CollectionDate, mgd.Gd_IsDeleted, mgd.Gd_CreateDate, mg.Grp_Project, mg.Grp_IsDeleted , mg.Grp_Legacy_ID,  p.LegacyProjectId
    INTO datasets
    FROM Savix_Service_Group..Group_Data mgd 
            INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Group_Cycle mgc ON mgc.Gc_ID = mgd.Gd_CycleID
            INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Groups mg ON mg.Grp_ID = mgc.Gc_GroupID 
            inner join SG_Dynamic_Forms..v_projects p ON p.ProjectID = mg.Grp_Project


DECLARE projects1 CURSOR LOCAL FOR Select distinct ProjectID, isnull([FacilitatingAgency], '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') from @projects P WHERE P.SystemStatus = 4 AND P.SyncMode = 1 
/*First cursor - fetch the cursor from ProjectaTable*/


OPEN projects1
FETCH NEXT FROM projects1 INTO @ProjectID, @FAID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN

        DELETE FROM T_PROJECTGROUPSDATA
            WHERE T_PROJECTGROUPSDATA.UPLOAD_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM T_UPLOADS WHERE project_savix_ID = @ProjectID AND UPLOADFILENAME = 'Automatic upload from web MIS')

        DECLARE datasets CURSOR LOCAL  FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT Gd_ID, Grp_ID, Gd_CollectionDate, Gd_IsDeleted, Gd_CreateDate 
            FROM datasets
            WHERE LegacyProjectId = @ProjectID AND Grp_IsDeleted = 0 AND Gd_IsDeleted != 1 
            /*Second cursor - this will get the 'collectionDate'field from datasetsTable for every project fetched in above cursor and also get @dataID which is used to insert value in to other table-T_PROJECTGROUPSDATA*/
        OPEN datasets

        FETCH NEXT FROM datasets INTO @DataID, @GroupID, @CollectionDate, @Status, @Createdate
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            DECLARE period CURSOR LOCAL  FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT ID, dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(ID) FROM T_PERIODS
            /* dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(ID) - this function will give the end of the date of that specifc quarter for any given date*/
                WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,@CollectionDate,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(ID)) >= 0
                ORDER BY [YEAR],[Quarter]
                /*Third Cursor - this will process the records from another table called period with above fetched @collectionDate*/

            OPEN period
            FETCH NEXT FROM period INTO @PeriodID, @EndDate
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN

                IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Savix_Service_Group..Group_Data mgd 
                    INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Group_Cycle mgc ON mgc.Gc_ID = mgd.Gd_CycleID
                    WHERE mgc.Gc_GroupID = @GroupID
                        AND DATEDIFF(dd,mgd.Gd_CollectionDate,@EndDate) >= 0 
                        AND (mgd.Gd_CollectionDate > @CollectionDate ) 
                        AND mgd.Gd_IsDeleted != 1) 

                BEGIN
                    BREAK
                END

                IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM T_UPLOADS u 
                    WHERE  u.project_savix_ID = @ProjectID AND u.PERIOD_ID = @PeriodID AND u.STATUS = 3 AND UPLOADFILENAME != 'Automatic upload from web MIS') 
                BEGIN
                    FETCH NEXT FROM period INTO @PeriodID, @EndDate
                    CONTINUE
                END

                SET @UploadID = (SELECT ID FROM T_UPLOADS u WHERE  u.project_savix_ID = @ProjectID AND u.PERIOD_ID = @PeriodID AND u.STATUS = 3)

                /*If T_uploads doesn't have appropirate period ID from cursor fetch then create a new entry in T_uploads with current projectID*/

                IF @UploadID IS NULL
                        BEGIN

                            declare @Project_ID_Legacy int = ISNULL((select distinct PROJECT_ID from T_UPLOADS where project_savix_ID = @ProjectID),@ProjectID)

                                INSERT INTO T_UPLOADSFIRSTSTEP
                                       (PROJECT_ID
                                       ,UPLOADDATE
                                       ,UPLOADFILENAME
                                       ,UPLOADUSER_ID
                                       ,CURRENTSTEP
                                       ,STATUS
                                       ,Project_ID_MIS)
                                 SELECT @Project_ID_Legacy , --mm 06/12
                                        GETDATE(),
                                        'Automatic upload from web MIS',
                                        2,
                                        2,
                                        0,
                                        @ProjectID

                                INSERT INTO T_UPLOADS
                                       (ID, periodID, projectID,UPLOADDATE,UPLOADFILENAME,UPLOADUSER_ID )
                                 SELECT uf.ID,
                                        @PeriodID,
                                        uf.PROJECT_ID,
                                        uf.UPLOADDATE,
                                        uf.UPLOADFILENAME,
                                        uf.UPLOADUSER_ID

                                 FROM T_UPLOADSFIRSTSTEP uf
                                 INNER JOIN @projects mp ON  uf.Project_ID_MIS = mp.ProjectID
                                 WHERE  uf.Project_ID_MIS = @ProjectID AND uf.STATUS = 0 
                                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T_UPLOADS u WHERE u.PROJECT_ID  = uf.PROJECT_ID AND u.PERIOD_ID = @PeriodID AND u.STATUS = 3)

                                DELETE FROM T_UPLOADSFIRSTSTEP WHERE STATUS = 0 AND PROJECT_ID = @Project_ID_Legacy 

                                SET @UploadID = (SELECT ID FROM T_UPLOADS u WHERE  u.project_savix_ID = @ProjectID AND u.PERIOD_ID = @PeriodID AND u.STATUS = 3)
                END ELSE
                            UPDATE T_UPLOADS SET 
                                TOTALEXPENDITURES = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,mp.StartDate,mp.EndDate) != 0 
                                            THEN mp.Cost_Until_Today*DATEDIFF(d,mp.StartDate,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(@PeriodID))/DATEDIFF(d,mp.StartDate,mp.EndDate)/dbo.fn_RateAtDate(mp.Currency,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(@PeriodID))
                                        ELSE 0 END,
                                TotalExpendituresNative = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,mp.StartDate,mp.EndDate) != 0 
                                            THEN mp.Cost_Until_Today*DATEDIFF(d,mp.StartDate,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(@PeriodID))/DATEDIFF(d,mp.StartDate,mp.EndDate)
                                        ELSE 0 END
                            FROM @projects mp
                            WHERE T_UPLOADS.ID = @UploadID AND mp.ProjectID = @ProjectID

                        INSERT INTO T_PROJECTGROUPSDATA 
                                (uploadID, fieldA,fieldB,......fieldN )

                         SELECT @UploadID,p.fieldA,mg.fieldB,......mgc.fieldN
                         FROM @projects mp
                         inner join  SG_Dynamic_Forms..v_projects p ON p.LegacyProjectId = mp.projectID 
                         inner join Savix_Service_Group..Groups mg ON mg.Grp_Project = p.ProjectID 
                         INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Group_Cycle mgc ON mgc.Gc_GroupID = mg.Grp_ID
                         INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Group_Data mgd ON mgd.Gd_CycleID = mgc.Gc_ID
                         LEFT JOIN Savix_Service_Trainers..Trainers me ON me.Tr_ID = mgc.Gc_MonitoredBy
                         LEFT JOIN Savix_Service_Dictionaries..Dictionary mgt ON mgt.Dny_ID = me.Tr_Type 
                         --left join v1_Report_UDF_Data_UploadToSavix udf on udf.DataID = mgd.Gd_ID
                         WHERE mgd.Gd_ID = @DataID 

                FETCH NEXT FROM period INTO @PeriodID, @EndDate
            END
            CLOSE period
            DEALLOCATE period

            FETCH NEXT FROM datasets INTO @DataID, @GroupID, @CollectionDate, @Status, @Createdate
        END

        CLOSE datasets
        DEALLOCATE datasets

        COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH



        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE(),@PeriodID, @ProjectID, @UploadID,@DataID
        IF CURSOR_STATUS('global' , 'period') >= 0
        BEGIN
            CLOSE period
            DEALLOCATE uploadID
        END

        IF CURSOR_STATUS('global' , 'datasets') >= 0
        BEGIN
            CLOSE datasets
            DEALLOCATE datasets
        END

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK

        INSERT INTO error_catch_UploadtoSavix

        SELECT cast(ERROR_NUMBER() as nvarchar), ERROR_MESSAGE(),@PeriodID, @ProjectID, @UploadID,@DataID, getdate()
    END CATCH


    FETCH NEXT FROM projects1 INTO @ProjectID, @FAID
END


CLOSE projects1
DEALLOCATE projects1

SELECT 1 as success
```

Here is what I've tried to do and stuck in middle and incomplete:

```
select s.ID,u.* 
from T_PROJECTS_TEMP pt 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT mgd.Gd_ID, mg.Grp_ID, mgd.Gd_CollectionDate, mgd.Gd_IsDeleted, mgd.Gd_CreateDate, mg.Grp_Project, mg.Grp_IsDeleted , mg.Grp_Legacy_ID,  p.LegacyProjectId
    FROM Savix_Service_Group..Group_Data mgd 
    INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Group_Cycle mgc ON mgc.Gc_ID = mgd.Gd_CycleID
    INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Groups mg ON mg.Grp_ID = mgc.Gc_GroupID 
    inner join SG_Dynamic_Forms..v_projects p ON p.ProjectID = mg.Grp_Project
    WHERE LegacyProjectId = 5047 AND Grp_IsDeleted = 0 AND Gd_IsDeleted != 1 )  dataset  on pt.ID = dataset.LegacyProjectId
INNER JOIN T_PERIODS s ON DATEDIFF(DAY,dataset.Gd_CollectionDate,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(s.ID)) >= 0 
LEFT JOIN T_UPLOADS u ON u.project_savix_ID = pt.ID AND u.PERIOD_ID = s.ID AND u.STATUS = 3 --AND u.UPLOADFILENAME != 'Automatic upload from web MIS'

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Savix_Service_Group..Group_Data mgd 
                    INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Group_Cycle mgc ON mgc.Gc_ID = mgd.Gd_CycleID
                    WHERE mgc.Gc_GroupID = Grp_ID
                        AND DATEDIFF(dd,mgd.Gd_CollectionDate,(select dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(s.ID))) >= 0 
                        AND (mgd.Gd_CollectionDate > Gd_CollectionDate) AND mgd.Gd_IsDeleted != 1 ) 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM T_UPLOADS u 
                    WHERE u.project_savix_ID = pt.ID AND u.PERIOD_ID = s.ID AND u.STATUS = 3 AND UPLOADFILENAME != 'Automatic upload from web MIS') 

ORDER BY s.ID
```

### Sample Data

Tables and data for T_Projects and datasets - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/00205/2

Tables and data for T_Periods - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3b6b1/2

Tables and data for T_uploads (before the cursor running)- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7d12f3/1

Other tables data 1 - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6e499

other tables data 2 - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/30e3b/3

function fn_getEndOFperiod - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/54d66

PLease note - there will be more than one row in any of the above tables, however the example I had given will have just one record.

### Excepted Data

T_uploads table  - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/027cc/1

T_ProjectsGroupData will have total of 15 records aswell i.e for every T_uploads.ID (which is relation to T_ProjectsGroupData .UploadID field) there will be a entry in T_ProjectsGroupData

I except this CURSOR based code to be converted in to a simple SET based approach, any help and suggestion to improve this code will be much much appreciable.

Comment: Please provide some example data for the tables used

Comment: I have added the sample data, please have a look

Comment: This is a [re-ask of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616585/how-to-convert-row-by-row-execution-in-to-set-based-approach-in-sql).

Comment: In the example half of the tables missing, like Savix tables, and functions.

Comment: Hi Vitaly I have added the required schema and data, please let me know still if anything I'm missing and I have added bounty for this question.

Comment: The data (DDL and DML statements) and expected results should *really* be in the question; you're asking the users to check a lot of off site links to be able to help you here. Include the DDL/DML and expected results inside your question please.

Comment: @Larnu, I tried but the text editor doesn't allow me to post more lines of code in it. So please excuse me for off site links.

Comment: You really should create a minimal code that reproduce the problem. If the sample data and the code are too large to fit inside an SO post, it probably means that your example is far from minimal. You have to realize that none of us is getting paid for answering questions. We do it on our spare time for free to help fellow developers, to learn, and to get help when we will need it - so expecting us to dive that deep inside someone else's work - that's simply not realistic. Sorry for the 50 reputation points you've spent, but I don't think that's going to help you with this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO T_PROJECTGROUPSDATA (uploadID, fieldA,fieldB,......fieldN )
SELECT t.ID,p.fieldA,mg.fieldB,......mgc.fieldN
FROM T_Projects mp
INNER JOIN T_UPLOADS t mp.ID = t.project_savix_ID
INNER JOIN  SG_Dynamic_Forms..v_projects p ON p.LegacyProjectId = mp.ID 
INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Groups mg ON mg.Grp_Project = p.ProjectID 
INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Group_Cycle mgc ON mgc.Gc_GroupID = mg.Grp_ID
INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Group_Data mgd ON mgd.Gd_CycleID = mgc.Gc_ID
LEFT JOIN Savix_Service_Trainers..Trainers me ON me.Tr_ID = mgc.Gc_MonitoredBy
LEFT JOIN Savix_Service_Dictionaries..Dictionary mgt ON mgt.Dny_ID = me.Tr_Type 
WHERE mp.SyncMode = 1
AND t.[STATUS] = 3 AND t.UPLOADFILENAME = 'Automatic upload from web MIS'
AND mg.Grp_IsDeleted = 0 AND mgd.Gd_IsDeleted != 1


UPDATE t SET 
TOTALEXPENDITURES = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,mp.PROJECTESTABLISHEDDATE,mp.EndDate) != 0 
    THEN p.Cost_Until_Today*DATEDIFF(d,mp.PROJECTESTABLISHEDDATE,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(t.Period_ID))/DATEDIFF(d,mp.PROJECTESTABLISHEDDATE,mp.EndDate)/dbo.fn_RateAtDate(p.PROJECTCURRENCY_ID,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(t.Period_ID))
    ELSE 0 
    END,
TotalExpendituresNative = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,mp.PROJECTESTABLISHEDDATE,mp.EndDate) != 0 
    THEN p.Cost_Until_Today*DATEDIFF(d,mp.PROJECTESTABLISHEDDATE,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(t.Period_ID))/DATEDIFF(d,mp.PROJECTESTABLISHEDDATE,mp.EndDate)
    ELSE 0 
    END
FROM T_UPLOADS t
JOIN T_Projects mp ON mp.ID = t.project_savix_ID AND mp.SyncMode = 1
WHERE t.[STATUS] = 3 AND t.UPLOADFILENAME = 'Automatic upload from web MIS'
```

To explain how I came up with this, here is a modified version of the code below.  I cannot guarantee I got everything, I had to make some assumptions. There was a lacking of sample data and all the savix tables are missing.  This is the best answer I can come up with given the information and limiting my time to less than 4 hours invested.  I could do much more but you would have to give me more than internet fame.

```
--ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_Upload]  WITH RECOMPILE 
--as
set NoCount on

DECLARE
    @StartTime      datetime,
    @EndTime        datetime,
    @DataID         uniqueidentifier,
    @CollectionDate datetime,
    @Status         int,
    @PeriodID       int,
    @EndDate        datetime,
    @GroupID        uniqueidentifier,
    @ProjectID      INT,
    @FAID           uniqueidentifier,
    @UploadID       int ,
    @Createdate datetime, 
    @MINIDprojects INT,
    @MAXIDprojects INT,
    @MINIDdatasets INT,
    @MAXIDdatasets INT,
    @MINIDperiods INT,
    @MAXIDperiods INT
```

It is difficult to work and test cursors, so I replaced them ( projects, projects1, datasets and period ) with temp tables containing an identity and looped through them.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#projects') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #projects
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#projects1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #projects1
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#datasets') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #datasets
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#period') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #period

CREATE TABLE #projects
(
    [ProjectID] [INT],
    [Title] [varchar](255) ,
    [currency] [int] ,
    [Cost_Until_Today] [float] ,
    [StartDate] [datetime] ,
    [EndDate] [datetime] ,
    [MisID] [uniqueidentifier] ,
    [SystemStatus] [int] ,
    [FacilitatingAgency] [uniqueidentifier] ,
    [SyncMode] [int] 
)

CREATE TABLE #projects1
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [ProjectID] [INT],
    [FacilitatingAgency] [uniqueidentifier]
)

CREATE TABLE #datasets
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Gd_ID [uniqueidentifier], 
    Grp_ID [uniqueidentifier], 
    Gd_CollectionDate DATETIME, 
    Gd_IsDeleted BIT, 
    Gd_CreateDate DATETIME
)

CREATE TABLE #period
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    IDPeriod INT,
    EndDate DATETIME
)

 INSERT #projects ( [ProjectID], [Title], {currency], [Cost_Until_Today], [StartDate], [EndDate], [MisID], [SystemStatus], [FacilitatingAgency], [SyncMode] )
 SELECT ID, PROJECTNAME, PROJECTCURRENCY_ID, Cost_Until_Today, PROJECTESTABLISHEDDATE, EndDate, MisID, 4, FacilitatingAgency, SyncMode 
 FROM [dbo].[T_PROJECTS] /*thsi is the source table where every projectIDs need to be processed*/
```

Projects contains all ID's ( projectID ) from T_Projects, the only fields that are used from this table are the ID, projectcurrency, projectestablisheddate ( startdate ), enddate and syncmode ( must be = 1, we will see that later ).  We can ignore systemstatus as it is a constant.

The table dastasets is dropped and loaded here.  We only care about the gd_id from the Savix_Service_Group..Group_Data table but still need to join to the other tables in case that they filter out values we don't want.  This logic is used again down below when inserting records.

```
IF exists ( select  * from    dbo.sysobjects where   id = object_id(N'[dbo].datasets]') and objectproperty(id, N'IsTable') = 1 ) DROP Table [dbo].datasets

SELECT mgd.Gd_ID, mg.Grp_ID, mgd.Gd_CollectionDate, mgd.Gd_IsDeleted, mgd.Gd_CreateDate, mg.Grp_Project, mg.Grp_IsDeleted , mg.Grp_Legacy_ID,  p.LegacyProjectId
INTO datasets
FROM Savix_Service_Group..Group_Data mgd 
        INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Group_Cycle mgc ON mgc.Gc_ID = mgd.Gd_CycleID
        INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Groups mg ON mg.Grp_ID = mgc.Gc_GroupID 
        inner join SG_Dynamic_Forms..v_projects p ON p.ProjectID = mg.Grp_Project

--DECLARE projects1 CURSOR LOCAL FOR Select distinct ProjectID, isnull([FacilitatingAgency], '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') from @projects P WHERE P.SystemStatus = 4 AND P.SyncMode = 1 
--/*First cursor - fetch the cursor from ProjectaTable*/

--OPEN projects1
--FETCH NEXT FROM projects1 INTO @ProjectID, @FAID
--WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
```

Here we are inserting into projects1 a distinct value of project id's.  Without more data, my assumption is that the ID is distinct in the T_projects table and therefore this step is somewhat unnecessary aside from filtering out by SyncMode = 1.  Remember that SystemStatus is a constant and we populated it with the value '4', this criteria could be removed with no effect.

```
INSERT INTO #projects1 ( ProjectID, FacilitatingAgency )
SELECT DISTINCT ProjectID, isnull([FacilitatingAgency], '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')  
FROM #projects p
WHERE SystemStatus = 4 AND SyncMode = 1

SELECT @MINIDprojects = MIN(ID), @MAXIDprojects = MAX(ID) FROM #projects1
WHILE @MINIDprojects < @MAXIDprojects + 1
BEGIN
--    BEGIN TRY
--        BEGIN TRAN

SELECT @ProjectID = ProjectID, @FAID = FacilitatingAgency FROM #projects1 WHERE ID = @MINIDprojects

        --DELETE FROM T_PROJECTGROUPSDATA WHERE T_PROJECTGROUPSDATA.UPLOAD_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM T_UPLOADS WHERE project_savix_ID = @ProjectID AND UPLOADFILENAME = 'Automatic upload from web MIS')

        --DECLARE datasets CURSOR LOCAL  FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT Gd_ID, Grp_ID, Gd_CollectionDate, Gd_IsDeleted, Gd_CreateDate 
        --    FROM datasets
        --    WHERE LegacyProjectId = @ProjectID AND Grp_IsDeleted = 0 AND Gd_IsDeleted != 1 
        --    /*Second cursor - this will get the 'collectionDate'field from datasetsTable for every project fetched in above cursor and also get @dataID which is used to insert value in to other table-T_PROJECTGROUPSDATA*/
        --OPEN datasets

        --FETCH NEXT FROM datasets INTO @DataID, @GroupID, @CollectionDate, @Status, @Createdate
        --WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
```

Here we insert into #datasets filtering by T_Project.ID AND Savix_Service_Group..Groups.Grp_IsDeleted = 0 AND Savix_Service_Group..Group_Data.Gd_IsDeleted != 1

```
        INSERT INTO #datasets ( Gd_ID, Grp_ID, Gd_CollectionDate, Gd_IsDeleted, Gd_CreateDate )
        SELECT Gd_ID, Grp_ID, Gd_CollectionDate, Gd_IsDeleted, Gd_CreateDate FROM datasets WHERE LegacyProjectId = @ProjectID AND Grp_IsDeleted = 0 AND Gd_IsDeleted != 1 

        SELECT @MINIDdatasets = MIN(ID), @MAXIDdatasets = MAX(ID) FROM #datasets

        WHILE @MINIDdatasets < @MAXIDdatasets + 1
        BEGIN

            SELECT @DataID = Gd_ID, @GroupID = Grp_ID, @CollectionDate = Gd_CollectionDate, @Status = Gd_IsDeleted, @Createdate = Gd_CreateDate FROM #datasets WHERE ID = @MINIDdatasets

            --DECLARE period CURSOR LOCAL  FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT ID, dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(ID) FROM T_PERIODS
            --/* dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(ID) - this function will give the end of the date of that specifc quarter for any given date*/
            --    WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,@CollectionDate,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(ID)) >= 0
            --    ORDER BY [YEAR],[Quarter]
            --    /*Third Cursor - this will process the records from another table called period with above fetched @collectionDate*/

            --OPEN period
            --FETCH NEXT FROM period INTO @PeriodID, @EndDate
            --WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
```

This is probably the worst use of a cursor here.  We load all the periods and cycle through them.  In the end we only care about periods that are in the T_UPLOADS table.

```
            INSERT INTO #period ( IDPeriod, EndDate ) SELECT ID, dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(ID) FROM T_PERIODS WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,@CollectionDate,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(ID)) >= 0
            SELECT @MINIDperiods = MIN(ID), @MAXIDperiods = MAX(ID) FROM #period

            WHILE @MINIDperiods < @MAXIDperiods + 1
            BEGIN

                --IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Savix_Service_Group..Group_Data mgd 
                --    INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Group_Cycle mgc ON mgc.Gc_ID = mgd.Gd_CycleID
                --    WHERE mgc.Gc_GroupID = @GroupID
                --        AND DATEDIFF(dd,mgd.Gd_CollectionDate,@EndDate) >= 0 
                --        AND (mgd.Gd_CollectionDate > @CollectionDate ) 
                --        AND mgd.Gd_IsDeleted != 1) 

                --BEGIN
                --    BREAK
                --END
```

Here we skip any periods where UPLOADFILENAME != 'Automatic upload from web MIS'

```
                --IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM T_UPLOADS u WHERE  u.project_savix_ID = @ProjectID AND u.PERIOD_ID = @PeriodID AND u.STATUS = 3 AND UPLOADFILENAME != 'Automatic upload from web MIS') 
                --BEGIN
                --    FETCH NEXT FROM period INTO @PeriodID, @EndDate
                --    CONTINUE
                --END
```

With that in mind we only care where status = 3 and UPLOADFILENAME = 'Automatic upload from web MIS'

```
                SET @UploadID = (SELECT ID FROM T_UPLOADS u WHERE  u.project_savix_ID = @ProjectID AND u.PERIOD_ID = @PeriodID AND u.[STATUS] = 3 AND UPLOADFILENAME = 'Automatic upload from web MIS')

                /*If T_uploads doesn't have appropirate period ID from cursor fetch then create a new entry in T_uploads with current projectID*/

                IF @UploadID IS NOT NULL
                        BEGIN

                            --declare @Project_ID_Legacy int = ISNULL((select distinct PROJECT_ID from T_UPLOADS where project_savix_ID = @ProjectID),@ProjectID)
```

Why they use a second table ( T_UPLOADFIRSTSTEP ) to generate a record where they only use the id and then delete the record using that ID in the creation of the T_Uploads record is beyond my understanding and appears to me to be terrible coding.

```
    --                            INSERT INTO T_UPLOADSFIRSTSTEP
    --                                   (PROJECT_ID
    --                                   --,UPLOADDATE
    --                                   --,UPLOADFILENAME
    --                                   --,UPLOADUSER_ID
    --                                   --,CURRENTSTEP
    --                                   ,[STATUS]
    --                                   ,Project_ID_MIS)
    --                             SELECT ISNULL((select distinct PROJECT_ID from T_UPLOADS where project_savix_ID = @ProjectID),@ProjectID),
    --                                    --GETDATE(),
    --                                    --'Automatic upload from web MIS',
    --                                    --2,
    --                                    --2,
    --                                    0,
    --                                    @ProjectID
```

The insert into T_UPLOADS will always fail as there are fields that can not be null that are not in the insert list and do not have a default value assigned to them.

```
    --                            INSERT INTO T_UPLOADS ( ID, periodID, projectID,UPLOADDATE,UPLOADFILENAME,UPLOADUSER_ID )
    --                             SELECT uf.ID,
    --                                    @PeriodID,
    --                                    ISNULL((select distinct PROJECT_ID from T_UPLOADS where project_savix_ID = @ProjectID),@ProjectID),
    --                                    GETDATE(),
    --                                    'Automatic upload from web MIS',
    --                                    2
    --                             FROM T_UPLOADSFIRSTSTEP uf
    --                             INNER JOIN #projects mp ON  uf.Project_ID_MIS = mp.ProjectID
    --                             WHERE  uf.Project_ID_MIS = @ProjectID AND uf.[STATUS] = 0 
    --                                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T_UPLOADS u WHERE u.PROJECT_ID  = uf.PROJECT_ID AND u.PERIOD_ID = @PeriodID AND u.[STATUS] = 3)

    --                            DELETE FROM T_UPLOADSFIRSTSTEP WHERE STATUS = 0 AND PROJECT_ID = ISNULL((select distinct PROJECT_ID from T_UPLOADS where project_savix_ID = @ProjectID),@ProjectID)

    --                            --SET @UploadID = (SELECT ID FROM T_UPLOADS u WHERE  u.project_savix_ID = @ProjectID AND u.PERIOD_ID = @PeriodID AND u.[STATUS] = 3)
    --            END 
                --ELSE
```

So here is the real logic that is done inside those 3 cursors.  Understanding that we don't care about periods, the logic loops through them all.  We only care that we have to filter certain criteria ( status = 3 and UPLOADFILENAME = 'Automatic upload from web MIS' ) and that they have a matching T_Project.ID table with the criteria T_Projects.SyncMode = 1

```
                            UPDATE t SET 
                                    TOTALEXPENDITURES = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,mp.StartDate,mp.EndDate) != 0 
                                            THEN mp.Cost_Until_Today*DATEDIFF(d,mp.StartDate,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(t.Period_ID))/DATEDIFF(d,mp.StartDate,mp.EndDate)/dbo.fn_RateAtDate(mp.Currency,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(t.Period_ID))
                                            ELSE 0 
                                            END,
                                    TotalExpendituresNative = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,mp.StartDate,mp.EndDate) != 0 
                                            THEN mp.Cost_Until_Today*DATEDIFF(d,mp.StartDate,dbo.fn_GetEndOfPeriod(t.Period_ID))/DATEDIFF(d,mp.StartDate,mp.EndDate)
                                            ELSE 0 
                                            END
                            FROM T_UPLOADS t
                            JOIN #projects mp ON mp.ProjectID = t.project_savix_ID
                            WHERE 1=1 -- t.ID = @UploadID 
                            --AND t.project_savix_ID = @ProjectID AND t.PERIOD_ID = @PeriodID 
                            AND t.[STATUS] = 3 AND t.UPLOADFILENAME = 'Automatic upload from web MIS'
```

The insert into T_PROJECTGROUPDATA has duplicated the logic used to create the @dataid variable derived from #datasets.  Which is derived from the datasets table we dropped and created above.

```
                        INSERT INTO T_PROJECTGROUPSDATA (uploadID, fieldA,fieldB,......fieldN )

                         SELECT @UploadID,p.fieldA,mg.fieldB,......mgc.fieldN
                         FROM #projects mp
                         inner join  SG_Dynamic_Forms..v_projects p ON p.LegacyProjectId = mp.projectID 
                         inner join Savix_Service_Group..Groups mg ON mg.Grp_Project = p.ProjectID 
                         INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Group_Cycle mgc ON mgc.Gc_GroupID = mg.Grp_ID
                         INNER JOIN Savix_Service_Group..Group_Data mgd ON mgd.Gd_CycleID = mgc.Gc_ID
                         LEFT JOIN Savix_Service_Trainers..Trainers me ON me.Tr_ID = mgc.Gc_MonitoredBy
                         LEFT JOIN Savix_Service_Dictionaries..Dictionary mgt ON mgt.Dny_ID = me.Tr_Type 
                         --left join v1_Report_UDF_Data_UploadToSavix udf on udf.DataID = mgd.Gd_ID
                         WHERE mgd.Gd_ID = @DataID 

                --FETCH NEXT FROM period INTO @PeriodID, @EndDate
                SET @MINIDperiods = @MINIDperiods + 1
            END
            --CLOSE period
            --DEALLOCATE period

            --FETCH NEXT FROM datasets INTO @DataID, @GroupID, @CollectionDate, @Status, @Createdate
            SET @MINIDdatasets = @MINIDdatasets + 1
        END

        --CLOSE datasets
        --DEALLOCATE datasets

        --COMMIT
    --END TRY
    --BEGIN CATCH



        --SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE(),@PeriodID, @ProjectID, @UploadID,@DataID
        --IF CURSOR_STATUS('global' , 'period') >= 0
        --BEGIN
        --    CLOSE period
        --    DEALLOCATE uploadID
        --END

        --IF CURSOR_STATUS('global' , 'datasets') >= 0
        --BEGIN
        --    CLOSE datasets
        --    DEALLOCATE datasets
        --END

        --IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        --    ROLLBACK

        --INSERT INTO error_catch_UploadtoSavix

        --SELECT cast(ERROR_NUMBER() as nvarchar), ERROR_MESSAGE(),@PeriodID, @ProjectID, @UploadID,@DataID, getdate()
    --END CATCH

    SET @MINIDprojects = @MINIDprojects + 1
    --FETCH NEXT FROM projects1 INTO @ProjectID, @FAID
END


--CLOSE projects1
--DEALLOCATE projects1

--SELECT 1 as success
```

There you have it.  Condensing nearly 300 lines and 3 cursors down to 30 lines and no cursors.